# returning sum of relationships propertys on path on neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to get the sum of properties of the **relationships**, from the returned list of a function like the next one

```
MATCH path=((house:Building {country: 'usa'})-[*]-(shelf:Building {country: 'mexico'}))
RETURN path;
```

The relationships can have differents names, but the propertys have the same keys(and different values), for example:

```
MERGE (house)-[:NAME1{num: '5'}]->(cabin)
MERGE (cabin)-[:NAME2{num: '10'}]->(shop)
MERGE (shop)-[:NAME1{num: '5'}]->(foo)
MERGE (foo)-[:NAME3{num: '30'}]->(shelf)
```

I need a query, applying the previous requirements, returning the sum of all relationship's properties.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [REDUCE function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-reduce) to calculate the total:

```
MATCH path=((house:Building {country: 'usa'})-[rels*]-(shelf:Building {country: 'mexico'}))
RETURN path, REDUCE(s = 0, r IN rels | s + TOINTEGER(r.num)) AS total;
```

*NOTE: Ideally, you should store integer values for the `num` property (instead of strings), so that you will not have to pay a performance penalty for converting all the string values to integers every time you need to use the numeric values. After you do that, you can remove the call to the `TOINTEGER` function.*

Comment: Couldn't use TOINT function, but my values were int so i removed this call and it worked fine.

Comment: Cypher replaced `TOINT` with `TOINTEGER` at some point. I have updated my answer.